# MSBuild attempts to load a dll with tasks from GAC

Tags: build, msbuild, task, gac

MSBuild fails when using the **UsingTask** element with the **AssemblyFile** attribute. It cannot find the assembly when importing a task in following manners:

```
<UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)ESRI.ArcGIS.Server.SDK.BuildTasks.dll" TaskName="GenerateServerAddInXml" />
```

The assembly file, however, exists and is in the right path. Fusion log reveals that MSBuild does not bother to search at the specified path and probes only in MSBuild.exe directory and then in GAC where the dll is not present.

```
LOG: Post-policy reference: ESRI.ArcGIS.Server.SDK.BuildTasks, Version=10.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/ESRI.ArcGIS.Server.SDK.BuildTasks.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/ESRI.ArcGIS.Server.SDK.BuildTasks/ESRI.ArcGIS.Server.SDK.BuildTasks.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/ESRI.ArcGIS.Server.SDK.BuildTasks.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/ESRI.ArcGIS.Server.SDK.BuildTasks/ESRI.ArcGIS.Server.SDK.BuildTasks.EXE.
```

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/usingtask-element-msbuild?view=vs-2017) says that the **AssemblyFile** attribute is equivalent to the  **Assembly.LoadFrom** method in .NET.

Interestingly, this same mechanism works for another dll just fine. Any ideas where the problem could be? 
There is actually a difference among these dlls - the latter is not strongly signed.

**Update:** I removed the strong signature from the dll (with help of *ildasm* and *ilasm*) and it still does not work.